# Galaxy S6 Battery Drop

Tags: battery, battery-life, 5.1-lollipop

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6, Stock ROM, running Android 5.1.1.

Last night, as I was browsing on my phone before I fell asleep, my battery dropped from 19% to 15% in an instant, engaging power save mode. It was concerning that the battery dropped like that, but I didn't think much of it. When I woke up this morning, I was using it again, starting at 9%. It then dropped instantly to 5%, engaging the Ultra power save.

I have never had my battery drop like this. I purchased the phone in November of 2015.

Attached are two screenshots, one from the Battery menu, and another from GSAM Battery Monitor.

[image]

[image]

Upon looking further at the stock settings graph, it seems to be dropping at other times too. Is this a sign of a failing battery? Should I bring the device in to my carrier for service?

Thank you!

Comment: Sudden percentage drop of the kind you mentioned (apart from other drops which could be wake lock related ) **is a reason for concern**. Your battery can't or shouldn't fail in 6 months even if you a real heavy user. Since you are covered by warranty, best to get it checked and seek replacement

Comment: I don't have wake lock information, as my device is not rooted. The battery did drop again, without my noticing, last night. I suspect that the Tumblr application may be responsible, so I am testing a full charge without running the application.

Comment: Ideally test out in safe mode-installed apps are not acTive in that mode